# Issue with Asynctasks and running multiple

Tags: android, service, asynchronous

I am looking to have multiple asynctasks but each one might possible need to be stopped while its running. Whats the most effective way to do this while having limitless running async task?

Right now in my code I would have:

```
ProgressTask task1; 
ProgressTask task2; 
ProgressTask task3;
```

but its too messy and difficult to manage that all and if I want to have 50 of those I would have to make 50 of them + code it in my app to determine which one to choose. So how can I do this?

Comment: Could you tell us why you would need 50 of them? What is your main goal?

Comment: Using List or Map manage your collection, for instance, Map<Key, AsyncTask>.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html read through this, your answer is there

Personally i think you should just have the one Asynctask then use multiple methods within the asynctask to do what you need